# Snowflake - Privileges required to query snowflake Information schema views

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to Snowflake. Is it possible to query Information schema views for eg, SCHEMATA, TABLES, COLUMNS for all tables in a snowflake Db without having select access to the underlying tables. The requirement is to create a user/account that only has access to query metadata of the snowflake Db and should not have a select access to the table data. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Snowflake documentation:

> "The output of a view or table function depends on the privileges
>   granted to the user’s current role. When querying an
>   INFORMATION_SCHEMA view or table function, only objects for which the
>   current role has been granted access privileges are returned."

In other words, you won't see the metadata for objects you do not have access to when you query the INFORMATION_SCHEMA views.

To workaround, you can use a role like ACCOUNTADMIN that has permissions to all tables and populate a new table with results from the desired INFORMATION_SCHEMA views. Then give your new role access to that table. You may be able to even setup a task in Snowflake to regularly update the table.

References:

- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/info-schema.html#general-usage-notes
- https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/tasks.html#executing-sql-statements-on-a-schedule-using-tasks

Comment: Another idea here: https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00009F7v0tSAB/is-there-a-grant-permission-in-snowflake-which-is-equivalent-to-viewdefinition-in-sql-intent-is-make-a-particular-role-user-access-only-metadata-of-tables-but-not-permission-to-read-data-in-it-this-is-for-data-catalog

Answer (score 0):

I believe you won't see the object in information schema views. So you required privileges to access the object.

Answer (score 0):

The views in INFORMATION_SCHEMA display metadata about objects defined in the database, as well as metadata for non-database, account-level objects that are common across all databases.

There are 17 views available under INFORMATION_SCHEMA that holds information of Database level objects.
There are 8 views that holds information of Account level objects.

INFORMATION_SCHEMA is a read-only schema available automatically under each database. It stores metadata of all Snowflake objects built under the database.

Running Queries on INFORMATION_SCHEMA requires warehouse to be up and running which incurs Snowflake credits.

The output of a view or table function depend on the privileges granted to the user’s current role. When querying an INFORMATION_SCHEMA view or table function, only objects for which the current role has been granted access privileges are returned.

To use a database's information schema all you need is usage privilege on that database. The role in turn will only see content from the information schema that he/she has access to.