# SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sql-grant, information-schema

When I am trying to execute the below query GRANT USAGE on INFORMATION_SCHEMA, I am getting below error

GRANT MONITOR ON SCHEMA DEMO_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA TO ROLE ALATIONTEST;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA DEMO_DB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA TO ROLE ALATIONTEST;

SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on schema 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA'

I have tried with different roles SYSADMIN, ACCOUNTADMIN, SECURITYADMIN still no luck.

Also, I could run the above GRANT query for other schemas, Only getting error with INFORMATION_SCHEMA

Please help on this.

Comment: Does the answer here help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294920/snowflake-privileges-required-to-query-snowflake-information-schema-views

Comment: What problem are you having that requires you to grant access to the `information_schema`? Is the alation role not able to see the information_schema for a database?

Comment: I need to fetch the Metadata of all the schema, tables, columns from the respective DB from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. So for that, Do I need to provide the privilege to my service account?

Answer (score 0):

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA schema is read-only for all users.  No explicit grants to that schema are necessary.

Comment: What about the tables and views under the INFORMATION_SCHEMA? Do we need to provide select privilege for those objects?

Comment: The objects that are available are mostly views or table functions, and they will all be read-only by default.  No need to grant anything to roles.