# Read-only privilege to view users in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to create a role with read-only access to the list of users in my Snowflake account. I am aware that I can grant the MANAGE GRANTS global privilege to my role to enable `SHOW USERS;`, as described [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/show-users.html#usage-notes):

```
create role auditor;
grant MANAGE GRANTS on account to role auditor;
```

But in my case I do not want this role to have permissions to do things like grant privileges. I just want this role to be able to read the list of users and various information about them. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered giving the role access to query the SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE views as opposed to the SHOW commands?  The views in the [ACCOUNT_USAGE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html) schema offer a lot of the same information and you can grant access to non-admins as mentioned [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#enabling-account-usage-for-other-roles).

Another idea if you don't want the user/role to have access to every ACCOUNT_USAGE view is using an administrator to capture/copy the results into a separate table and giving the role access to that table. You could even setup a task to periodically update the table.   An example article is [here](https://medium.com/hashmapinc/how-to-capture-snowflake-users-roles-and-grants-into-a-table-3ab3fd6cd0ce).

Comment: Thanks - SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE gives me the data I want. The only thing that's not ideal about this approach seems to be that these views have a latency of up to hours (https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#account-usage-views).

Comment: Correct, that's the downside.  The Information_Schema has the real-time data, but it has limitations and doesn't go back as far, so it depends what you prefer for the tradeoff. Here's a link to my post talking a little bit about permissions there:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58294920/snowflake-privileges-required-to-query-snowflake-information-schema-views

Comment: information_schema has some useful info for me, but I don't see a 'users' view there. information_schema.applicable_roles has some users, but not the full list. Any pointers to a query to get the full users list in information_schema?

Comment: Correct, one of the limitations is that it has less views to choose from, so the newer views like "Users" are not yet available there.  That would be a feature request. If the latency on Account_Usage.Users will not meet your business needs, then you can use an administrator to run the SHOW USERS commands and capture the results in a table that non-admins can utilize/query.  I linked this article before, but I will link it again if it helps:  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-Capture-Snowflake-Users-Roles-and-Grants-Into-a-Table